# WebView Download file from a POST request

Tags: android

I am trying to download a file from a website whose download button is of type submit inside a form. The form is making a post request to a url as follows

```
<form action="someUrl" classs="someClass" id="id" method="post" name="verify" autocomplete="off">
      <input class="Button " id="download" name="buttonOtp" type="submit" value="Download" onclick="return verifyForm();">
</form>
```

Here verifyForm() function does some verification of the form and then return back. Now the post request is called after that.

I tried to set a download listener to webView but the listener is not catching the event as the onDownloadStart() function is never get called.

Here a snippet of download Listener

```
 webView.setDownloadListener(new DownloadListener() {
        public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent,
                        String contentDisposition, String mimetype,
                        long contentLength) {

               //some code
        }
```

I tried printing some logs inside function, but nothing is printing.

Comment: Try inspecting and verifying that you really do send post request to that URL.

Comment: @TheKarlo95 I verified it through the console, it says "Request Method: POST"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of webview I moved on to custom tabs. There only I was able to handle the download part