# download file in webview return wrong data

Tags: android, browser, webview

```
  progressWebView.setDownloadListener((url1, userAgent, contentDisposition, mimetype, contentLength) -> {
    DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(url1));
    //------------------------COOKIE!!------------------------
    String cookies = CookieManager.getInstance().getCookie(url1);
    LogUtil.i(TAG, "cookie:" + cookies);
    request.addRequestHeader("Cookie", cookies);
    //------------------------COOKIE!!------------------------
    request.setMimeType(mimetype);
    request.addRequestHeader("Referer", RobotGlobalInfoShareCenter.referUrl);
    request.addRequestHeader("User-Agent", userAgent);
    request.setDescription("Downloading file...");
    request.setTitle(fileName);
    request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
    request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
    request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, fileName);
    DownloadManager dm = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
    long downloadId = dm.enqueue(request);
    LogUtil.i(TAG, "downloadId:{}" + downloadId);
});
```

but the file data is contain like
`<span class="errors">[crm.return.qrylistcenterrealtime.error]Undefined</span>`
not the normal data;
when I use Google Chrome or other browser,the file is right.I ensure the cookie and Refer is right,
Is I lose some Header or parameter?

Comment: i found where the problem is:it lose some data from previous page.but webSettings.setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(true) doesn't work ,what can i do?

Comment: thank you! [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53834571/webview-download-file-from-a-post-request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53834571/webview-download-file-from-a-post-request)